# Filtering out jenkins console output of a job

Tags: json, jenkins

I'm quite new in Jenkins and I would like to filter out from the jenkins console output only the json output of my unix script run via a jenkins job
To simplify my scenario, I have a MyScript unix script that returns a json output. A jenkins job wraps the MyScript execution using a "Execute shell" build action.
When I run the jenkins job, MyScript is executed and the jenkins console output returns below output:

```
Started by remote host ...
Building remotely on ... in workspace ...
Set build name.
New build name is '#11-/products/software/myScript.py'
[ScriptWrapper] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson9139846468482145951.sh
+ /products/software/myScript.py -t ...
{'ip': '...', 'host': '...'}
Set build name.
New build name is '#11-/products/software/myScript.py'
Variable with name 'BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME' already exists, ...
Finished: SUCCESS
```

From the above output I would like to filter out only the json output of my unix script that is "{'ip': '...', 'host': '...'}" .
That it is needed as we call the jenkins job via REST API and we need to get only the json output of the called unix script:

```
curl -s -k -u ... --request GET "https://<jenkins uri>/jenkins/view/ScriptWrapper/job/ScriptWrapper/19/consoleText"
```

We tried defining a parsing rules file but in this way we are able only to highlight some lines in the console output in the "Parsed Console Output" jenkins view.
In addition it seems that this "Parsed Console Output" is not accessible via rest api:

```
curl -s -k -u ... --request GET "https://<jenkins uri>/jenkins/view/ScriptWrapper/job/ScriptWrapper/19/parsed_console"
```

-> it doesn't work

Is there any way to filter out the jenkins console output?
We are also evaluating the possibility to use the Jenkins Groovy Postbuild Plugin. Do you think it can help ?
I thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you wish to generate clean output containing only the text you want?
If so, then I'd suggest you modify your shell script to output the desired text to a file, and then use either the "archive artifact" function in Jenkins to make the file content available, or the "html publisher" plugin to "publish" that file.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin

I third option could be to modify your shell script to output "magic cookies" as delimiters around the string you want.
That way you can fetch the entire console output using the REST API, and then easily filter out the text you want using a simple regex.

Comment: Hi Timmy,
yes, we wish to generate only json output returned by the script.
Third option is not applicable as:
1)external app calls jenkins rest api & expects ONLY xml/json result. It is not able to filter out text using regex
2)jenkins Execute shell build action to run myScript
3)myScript returns json output

Option html publisher:
ERR directory '/jenkins/workspace/ScriptWrapper/response' exists but failed copying to '/jenkins/jobs/ScriptWrapper/htmlreports/Job_Response'

How index.html should be structured?
Or myScript should return html output / should generate such index.html?

Comment: Hi Timmy,
I'm sorry, below more details about the error using the html publisher:

Option html publisher:
HTML dir: ./response
Index page: index.html
Report title: Job Response
ERROR: Directory '/jenkins/workspace/ScriptWrapper/response' exists but failed copying to '/jenkins/jobs/ScriptWrapper/htmlreports/Job_Response'
ERROR: This is especially strange since your build otherwise succeeded

Comment: Not sure about those errors from the html publisher. It should be capable of publishing any file. Have you tried the "archive artifact" function?